# Sort a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

I want to create function which sorts list. For example I have this list:

```
x1, x2, x3 .... xn
```

or

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

I want to display the numbers in this order:

```
x1, xn, x2, xn-1
```

or

```
1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4
```

Can you help me to write this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when we talk about sorting, we refer to ordering the items by some characteristic of the item contents, not the item position in the list. I would call your situation permuting, but perhaps some people might dispute that usage, too. :-)

Here's how you might approach the problem:

1. Split the list in the middle (you can do this using tortoise-and-hare if you only want to traverse the list once); call those lists `head` and `tail`, if you want.
2. Reverse the `tail` list, and interleave it with the `head` list.

Another approach:

1. Reverse the original list pairs (let's call it `rev`).
2. Interleave the original list with `rev`, keeping track of the element traversed each time. When they meet in the middle, stop.

Here's a demonstration of the second approach (requires [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) to be loaded):

```
(define (zippy lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (let recur ((lst lst)
                  (rev (pair-fold cons '() lst)))
        (cond ((eq? lst (car rev)) (list (car lst)))
              ((eq? (cdr lst) (car rev)) (list (car lst) (caar rev)))
              (else (cons* (car lst) (caar rev)
                           (recur (cdr lst) (cdr rev))))))))
```

Comment: ...and Óscar López's answer demonstrates the first approach. :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a sorting operation, more like a shuffling; here's another way to solve it. First, let's define the `interleave` procedure that alternates elements from two lists, returning a single list:

```
(define (interleave l1 l2)
  (cond ((empty? l1) l2)
        ((empty? l2) l1)
        (else (cons (first l1)
                    (interleave l2 (rest l1))))))
```

Now we take the original list and [`split-at`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=interleave#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._split-at%29%29) the middle (this is a Racket-specific procedure); finally we interleave the two resulting lists, reversing the tail:

```
(define (zippy lst)
  (let-values (((head tail) (split-at lst (quotient (length lst) 2))))
    (interleave head (reverse tail))))
```

The above implementation IMHO is a bit more intuitive, and if you're working with Racket it doesn't require external libraries. It works as expected:

```
(zippy '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> '(1 6 2 5 3 4)
```

Comment: Very nice. :-) Notes for non-Racket implementations: `split-at` is part of [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html), and `let-values` is part of [SRFI 11](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-11/srfi-11.html). If your implementation doesn't have SRFI 11, you can also easily convert to use `receive` from [SRFI 8](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-8/srfi-8.html), or alternatively you can use `call-with-values` directly, though the latter is uglier. :-)

Comment: BTW, I think `(/ (length lst) 2)` returns a non-integral number for an odd-lengthed list, which `split-at` might not like. `(quotient (length lst) 2)` may work better.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young you're of course, right. Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: I see one problem. How I can sort the numbers if I have this order: `4, 2, 9, 3, 5, 1` How I can sort them?

Comment: The ordering you defined in the question seems to depend on the position of the elements, not in their values. If the values are relevant, then sort the list first before feeding it to my function, use the `sort` procedure