# How to sort disorder list of numbers in scheme

Tags: scheme

What it the proper way to sort a list with values in Scheme? For example I have the values which are not ordered:

```
x1, x5, x32 .... xn
```

or

```
3, 4, 1, 3, 4, .. 9
```

First I want to for them by increase number and display them in this order:

```
x1, xn, x2, xn-1
```

or

```
1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4
```

Any help will be valuable.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same question you posted [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797858/sort-a-list-in-scheme/16799751), but with a small twist. As I told you in the comments of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16799751/201359), you just have to sort the list before rearranging it. Here's a Racket solution:

```
(define (interleave l1 l2)
  (cond ((empty? l1) l2)
        ((empty? l2) l1)
        (else (cons (first l1)
                    (interleave l2 (rest l1))))))

(define (zippy lst)
  (let-values (((head tail) (split-at
                             (sort lst <) ; this is the new part
                             (quotient (length lst) 2))))
    (interleave head (reverse tail))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(zippy '(4 2 6 3 5 1))
=> '(1 6 2 5 3 4)
```

Comment: By the way is there any other way to solve this task? This works but I'm looking for other ways. For example is there any algorithm that can be used?

Comment: @Peter You "can" (use selection for each position, for example) but it will be really slow!

Comment: Would you please show me how this can be solved with selection for each position. Speed is not a problem.

Comment: @PeterPenzov What "other ways" are you looking for? you're asking if there is any algorithm that can be used - sure, the _sorting_ algorithm shown above :P . Any attempt to rearrange the elements in the way you want without sorting the list first will end up being at least as slow as sorting the elements first, if not worse - because the desired ordering implicitly needs a sorted list. So go ahead and sort it first!

Comment: @PeterPenzov Well, I posted a separate post about the approach I just described, but trust me, it's inferior to the sort-first approach.

Answer (score 1):

This R6RS solution does what Chris Jester-Young proposes and it really is how to do it the bad way. BTW Chris' and Óscar's solutions on the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797858/sort-a-list-in-scheme/16799751) without sorting is superior to this zippy procedure.

```
    #!r6rs
    (import (rnrs base)
            (rnrs sorting)) ; list-sort

    (define (zippy lis)
      (let loop ((count-down (- (length lis) 1))
                 (count-up 0))
        (cond ((> count-up count-down) '())
              ((= count-up count-down) (cons (list-ref lis count-down) '()))
              (else (cons (list-ref lis count-down)
                          (cons (list-ref lis count-up)
                                (loop (- count-down 1)
                                      (+ count-up 1))))))))
    (define (sort-rearrange lis)
      (zippy (list-sort < lis)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple, tail-recursive approach that uses a 'slow/fast' technique to stop the recursion when half the list is traversed:

```
(define (interleave l)
  (let ((l (list-sort < l)))
    (let merging ((slow l) (fast l) (revl (reverse l)) (rslt '()))
      (cond ((null? fast)
             (reverse rslt))

            ((null? (cdr fast)) 
             (reverse (cons (car slow) rslt)))

            (else
             (merging (cdr slow) (cddr fast) (cdr revl)
                      (cons (car revl) (cons (car slow) rslt))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you don't mind slow and just want a selection-based approach, eh? Here we go....

First, we define a `select1` function that gets the minimum (or maximum) element, followed by all the other elements. For linked lists, this is probably the simplest approach, easier than trying to implement (say) quickselect.

```
(define (select1 lst cmp?)
  (let loop ((seen '())
             (rest lst)
             (ext #f)
             (extseen '()))
    (cond ((null? rest)
           (cons (car ext) (append-reverse (cdr extseen) (cdr ext))))
          ((or (not ext) (cmp? (car rest) (car ext)))
           (let ((newseen (cons (car rest) seen)))
             (loop newseen (cdr rest) rest newseen)))
          (else
           (loop (cons (car rest) seen) (cdr rest) ext extseen)))))
```

Now actually do the interweaving:

```
(define (zippy lst)
  (let recur ((lst lst)
              (left? #t))
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (let ((selected (select1 lst (if left? < >))))
          (cons (car selected) (recur (cdr selected) (not left?)))))))
```

This approach is O(n²), whereas the sort-and-interleave approach recommended by everybody else here is O(n log n).