# Compare odd and even numbers in a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying make an iterative procedure which compare every odd and every even elements in a list. Every odd number should be odd and every even should be even. First number must be odd.
Output should be like this:

```
(odd-even-args? 1 2 3 4 5) --> #t
(odd-even-args? 1 2 4 4 5) --> #f
(odd-even-args? 1 0 1) --> #t
```

I tried to compare two element with this: `(and (odd? (car lst)) (even? (cadr lst))`, but I don't know how to continue with `(cddr lst)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one possibility: traverse all the list, asking if each element satisfies the appropriate predicate (either `even?` or `odd?`) and alternate between the predicates:

```
(define (odd-even-args? . lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (is-odd? #t))
    (if (null? lst)
        #t
        (and ((if is-odd? odd? even?) (car lst))
             (loop (cdr lst) (not is-odd?))))))
```

The answer above uses an `and` with the recursive call in a tail position, so it's iterative - and it's similar to the way you were thinking about the solution. Here's another solution which shows more explicitly that this is indeed an iterative process:

```
(define (odd-even-args? . lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (is-odd? #t))
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          (((if is-odd? even? odd?) (car lst)) #f)
          (else (loop (cdr lst) (not is-odd?))))))
```

And yet another solution, using boolean connectors instead of conditional expressions:

```
(define (odd-even-args? . lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (is-odd? #t))
    (or (null? lst)
        (and ((if is-odd? odd? even?) (car lst))
             (loop (cdr lst) (not is-odd?))))))
```

Comment: Be aware that in R6RS, procedure comparisons do not have a guaranteed specific result. In particular, the result of `(let ((p (lambda (x) x))) (eqv? p p))` and `(let ((p (lambda (x) x))) (eq? p p))` are unspecified (but must still be boolean). It is for that reason that [my answer to a recent post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16973455/13) uses a flag, `left?` in my case, to specify the toggle value. (But, unintuitively given the above, `(eq? car car)` is specified to return true. Go figure. Maybe your solution may work after all.)

Comment: The 9th R7RS draft resolves this confusion: `(eq? car car)` is also unspecified. (But this whole "procedures are not necessarily `eq?` to themselves" thing is highly controversial, and [it will be revoked in the 10th draft](http://trac.sacrideo.us/wg/wiki/NinthDraftEditorialCorrections).)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I'll have this in mind, for now I'm snarfing your toggle flag :)

Comment: Strange to have this in the spec, I'd rather have (eq? (lambda (x) (* x x)) (lambda (y) (* y y))) be unspecified since it might be constant folded. Though I would consider (eq? car cdr) be unspecified when car and cdr is not used elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Just another variant ( probably not good one .. )

```
(define (odd-even-args? . args)
  (define (iter lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((null? (cdr lst)) (odd? (car lst)))
          ((and (odd? (car lst)) (even? (cadr lst))) (iter (cddr lst)))
          (else #f)))
  (iter args))
```

Comment: I tried something similar but it didn't work. Your solution is better than mine. I wrote mistake in `(else #f)`.

Comment: I have just rewrote your code with lambda expression, it is better for me: `(define odd-even-args?
  (lambda lst
    (let od-ev-a ((x lst))
      (cond ((null? x) #t)
            ((null? (cdr x)) (odd? (car x)))
            ((and (odd? (car x)) (even? (cadr x))) (od-ev-a (cddr x)))
            (else #f)))))`

Comment: Yep, such solution is first, that comes to mind. But Óscar López's solution is cool one.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (range start end)
  (if (>= start end)
      nil
      (cons start (range (+ start 1) end)))

(define (odd-even-args? . args)
  (apply and
         (map (lambda (value index)
                      (eqv? (even? index)
                            (even? value)))
              args
              (range 1 (+ 1 (length args))))))
```

Comment: You can't apply special forms in at least some versions of scheme, mit-scheme for sure. and is one such special form

Comment: sometime boolean/and is available which can be applied, but ends up evaluating all of the arguments in the list (which and avoids by being a special form and evaluating left to right)

Answer (score 0):

Why not design the general case as a higher order function and implement odd-even? as a special case? that way you can also implement even-odd?, or square?-tan?, or prime?-carmicheal? quite easily.

```
(define (predx?-predy? predx predy)
 (lambda L
  (let loop ((lst L) (pred?1 predx) (pred?2 predy))
   (if (null? lst)
       #t
       (and (pred?1 (car lst)) (loop (cdr lst) pred?2 pred?1)))))) 
 ;;flip  preds each recursion

(define odd-even? (predx?-predy? odd? even?))

(define even-odd? (predx?-predy? even? odd?))

(define square-tan (predx?-predy? square? tan?))

(define prime?-Carmichael? (predx?-predy? prime? (lambda (x) (and (not (prime? x)) (fermat-prime? x)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an exercise, I wrote a version using SRFI-1 and fold:

```
(define (odd-even-args? . xs)
  (first
    (fold
      (lambda (x data)
        (let ((result (first data))
              (count (second data)))
          (list
            (and
              ((if
                 (odd? count)
                 odd?
                 even?)
               x)
              result)
            (+ 1 count))))
      '(#t 1)
      xs)))
```