# Sorted point list by value from origin (scheme)

Tags: list, scheme, points

I am trying to write a procedure that sorts my points in a new list based on their distance from the origin `(0.0)` in ascending order. So, I first started by saying `(define origin (cons 0 0))` Then, I wrote a procedure that takes the minimum distance value to the origin:

```
(define (min-distance-origin p pt-list)
  (if (null? pt-list)
      0
      (min (distance (get-first-point pt-list) origin)
           (min-distance-origin (get-rest-points pt-list) origin)))
```

Then the next step I took was actually writiing the procedure for the sorted point list, though I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

```
(define (make-sorted-pt-list p pt-list)
(if (null? pt-list)
    0
    (min (min-distance-origin p origin) ; need something that can do (cons min ())
         (make-sorted-pt-list (car (cdr pt-list)) origin)))) ; recursive call
```

The problem I'm having is that I need something that can construct a list from the minimum value, then eliminate that value from the point list, and repeat.

Comment: I think you'll find that this always returns `0`.  Eventually you get to the base case which returns `0`, and then one call out from there you'll be doing `(min <something> 0)`, and the `0` will work its way all the way back up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a list in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797858/sort-a-list-in-scheme)

Comment: Scheme has a built-in sort for lists. Use that, just define a custom predicate (define (make-sorted pt-list) (sort (lambda (x y) (< (distance origin x) (distance origin y))) pt-list))

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs sorting))

(define (make-sorted-pt-list pt-list)
  (list-sort (lambda (p1 p2) (< (distance-origin p1)
                                (distance-origin p2)))
             pt-list))
```

You only need to make is `distance-origin`, a procedure that calculates the distance between origin and the supplied point. With this, making min is easy:

```
(define (min-distance-origin pt-list)
  (apply min (map distance-origin pt-list)))
```